# Perl: Generating an Array of hashes from a file

Tags: perl, hashtable

I'm trying to create an array of hashes that contains student names as the keys and multiple grades as the values for each student so that I can compute the average for each student, sort the averages in descending order, and print the "lastname, firstname: grade average" of each student in the sorted order.
The issue i'm having is with the generation of the array of hashes which I'm 90% sure the problem lies in the split on line 10 but I can't seem to find the solution myself.

students.txt:

```
chipper jones 29 80 70
hank aaron 99 85 81 75
beth allen 64 84 71 5x9 38 68 53
andruw jones 100 100 100 100 100
ty cobb 75 75 100
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#Program 5

my @Aoh;

open (FILEIN, "$ARGV[0]");

while(<FILEIN>) {
    chomp;
    push @Aoh, { split / / };

    for $i (0 .. $#Aoh) {
        print "{ ";
        for $role (keys %{ $Aoh[$i] }) {
            print " $role $Aoh[$i]{$role} ";
        }
    print "}\n";
    }
}
```

output I'm getting:

```
0 is { chipper=jones 70= 29=80 }
1 is { 81=75 hank=aaron 99=85 }
2 is { 38=68 53= beth=allen 64=84 71=5x9 }
3 is { 100= andruw=jones }
4 is { ty=cobb 75=75 100= }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
push @Aoh, { split / / };
```

Creates the following hash from the first line:

```
{ chipper => 'jones',
  29      => 80,
  70      => undef,
}
```

That's not what you wanted, right?

I'd use a hash of numbers instead of the array of hashes. You can use "lastname, firstname" directly as the hash key and you can store the averages directly as the values:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw{ sum };

my %average;

while (<>) {
    my ($name, $surname, @grades) = split;
    $average{"$surname, $name"} = sum(@grades) / @grades;
}

for my $student (sort { $average{$a} <=> $average{$b} } keys %average) {
    print $student, ' ', $average{$student}, "\n";
}
```

Note that I'm getting a warning:

> Argument "5x9" isn't numeric in subroutine entry at ./1.pl line 11, <> line 3.

How should one treat the `5x9` grade?

Comment: I'm supposed to be able to record, ignore, and report any entries with incorrect data like the 5x9

Comment: Feel free to add validation before populating the hash.

Comment: I thnk 5x9 is a typo. Its probably 59

Comment: It is meant to be there so that you can test catching bad input data.  I need to catch any invalid grade data and report it after computing and reporting all the good data

Comment: you can use the `looks_like_number` function from the core `Scalar::Util` module to catch non-numeric strings.